# Не работает конвертер

Tags: libgdx

Не работает fbx-conv

Выскакивает что не является win32.
На сайте пишут что нужно обновить vs2010, но он жалуется на наличие более новой версии.

Думаю что ему нужно скормить необходимые dll. 
запустить через javaGui.
Вывело:

> It's possible you either selected the wrong executable file, or you don't have fbx-conv installed correctly.
>   If you're on mac or linux be sure that libfbxsdk.dylib and libfbxsdk.so are in /usr/lib

Встречалась такая проблема у кого либо еще? Если да то как решали?

Comment: Покажи что тебе в терминале выводит.

Comment: Я из под windows запускаю. Если бы запускал из под линукса, то думаю проблем бы не было. Но ради этого ставить линуху... Я использую XP,файл собран под х32, так что должно работать, но не работает

Comment: Без разницы как в винде называется терминал или консоль, просто покажите что выводит.

Comment: Ни чего не выводит,вообще. То что я написал вывело в javaGui, по сути автоматизация конвертирования. Не запускается сам файл fbx-conv-win32.exe

Comment: Может просто не то скачали? Запустил под windows 8.1 32-bit у меня все работает. Вот md5 моего файла fbx-conv-win32.exe: 03cba961c9d0bf5719daf9a012c197c0. Проверьте у себя. И может лучше перейти хотя бы на семерку?

Comment: Походу косяк самой винды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Использовал XPюшку в которой проблема с новыми библиотеками. Нормально запустилась из под win7.
Также вместо предлагаемой vcredist_vs2010 нужно было поставить vcredist_vs2013